# Stuck on frozen frame using online CRM Dynamics

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-online

Every now and then (and sufficiently often to be bothered by), I get stuck in a modal window when e.g. creating a new filter, task, appointment etc. The window is movable but I can't close it by pressing the red X in the corner, save-and-close-it nor F4 it. The window lives and the buttons react visually **but** the frame doesn't close.

My best solution this far is to kill the process and log in again. That makes me sad...

I suspect that the behavior *might* have to do with my system configuration: I'm on Win8 with IE10 (set to compatibility mode) powered by CRM Dynamics 2011 in the cloud.

1. Can someone confirm the behavior?
2. Any hits on how to deal with it (other than installing IE9)?

(Before I'd set the compatibility mode on, I experienced some funny effects such as the "Get started"-section rolling and getting wider and wider like some cool jQuery-effect. Now it's under control, though.)

Comment: Rollup 10 (ver. 5.0.9690.2187)

Comment: This far, the only viable option that I've come up with is the pragmatically oriented solution to install IE9 and go with it. By that logic one can eliminate all bugs in software by going back to the stone age but it's hardly a feasible solution for a modern person...

Comment: Hmm, it is meant to be compatibile now, but this article suggests there are still bugs. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2743941 (Known issues).

Comment: FWIW I've experienced this (albeit rarely ~once "every" 3 days) and I use Win 7 and IE9 (64bit).

Comment: @James I don't believe that CRM Online is on UR10 yet. Notwithstanding my experience, perhaps the low patch-level of CRM Online might explain why the KB contradicts real-life? Current version number is 5.0.9690.2187 which technically precedes UR7 (!)

Comment: According to the info I've found on the net, it's supposed to be RU10 and the version number (5.0.9690.2187) is taken from "Help" section of my Dynamics On-line. On the other hand I've been CRM-ing for ten days now, so don't take my word for it.

Comment: Hi Konrad - would you have a link for that? I suspect it isn't the case, since [Rollup 7 is 05.00.9690.2165](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/8062.crm-2011-build-and-version-numbers.aspx) (made a mistake in earlier comment) and [Rollup 8 is 05.00.9690.2243](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/8062.crm-2011-build-and-version-numbers.aspx) so CRM Online is implied at Rollup 7.x :)

Comment: Yes it's [here](http://bingsoft.wordpress.com/2012/08/16/crm-2011-rollup-10-now-available/). I'm assuming that the roll up version 10 refers to the 9 after 5.0 (since roll up #1 would have a zero). Am I sadly mistaken?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not a solution, but have you changed your IE settings to force new popups to open as a new tab, instead of a new window?  I've never experienced the issue you describe, but it may allow you to close it, since it is a tab, and not a window...

Comment: I've thought about that too. It's not it, though. +1 because it's still a valid point. COngrats on joining the 2k club!